# Laravel angularJS local host cannot be accesed from another computer inside my network

Tags: php, angularjs, server, localhost

I have a proyect that is working on my main machine. I use the php -S localhost:8080 -t public command to start a local server. It works perfectly. But now I want to access it from another computer inside my own network but it does not work. In my other computer I type the ip address of the computer with the php server running like this 192.168.1.135:8080, but it does not connect. It just gives me timed out error. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of localhost:8080, I changed it to 0.0.0.0:8080. That did the trick.